# How to pass the real data in load testing using ApacheBench?

Tags: load-testing, apachebench

Our project is almost over.now we are going to  load testing..We have tested static page using below comment `ab -kc 1000 -n 10000 http://www.sample.com/index.php`

Now, how to pass real data so that i can check load testing.

Comment: I have refer below links it's use full for viewers 

 1  https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/how-benchmark-stress-your-apache-nginx-or-iis-server.html

2 http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/load-testing-apache-with-ab-apache-bench

3 https://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Post Method :**

```
 ab -n 1 -c 1   -p text.txt  -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890"   www.project.com/post_data.php
```

Text File  have below type of formated data.

```
text.txt

 --1234567890
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_token"

 MTQ3NDg2ODQxMjExOTAxMQ==
 --1234567890
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="admmin.jpg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg

 Base64 (Image Code Put Here)
 --1234567890--
```

- Content-Disposition is form-data
- name is posted data name
- Content-Type : if you have use any file it's must and give the file values as Base64 formate
- one space is must between value and contents description

**In Get Method :**

Use Below method to post

`**ab -n 1 -c 1   http://sample.com/api/v1.0/users/authentication/forgot_password.php?data="{\"email\":\"exmple@gmail.com\",\"type\":\"ut\"}"**`